# Different ressonant frequencies for velocity and displacement

Tags: waves, vibrations

For a damped oscilator, by working ou the math one can easily see that the ressonant frequency for the displacement is slightly lower than the one for velocity. But why? How we see this intuitively?

Comment: For a fixed displacement amplitude, the velocity is proportional to the frequency. Note that in some situations the applied *force* is also depends on the frequency, and in that situation what you noticed might not be correct.